# c# datagridview column autosizemode

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, autoresize, datagridtemplatecolumn

I wish that by default the columns uses the

```
AutoSizeMode = DisplayedCells;
```

but I wish also the possibility to resize the columns, but `DisplayedCells` type doesn't allow to resize..

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that because the AutoSizeMode once is set to DisplayedCells all the behavior is controlled by design. But I have this idea. You should have to keep your column (I suppose Columns[0] for demonstrative purpose) AutoSizeMode fixed at `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None`. You want to set it as `DisplayedCells` because you may want the column width to expand or collapse depending on the Cell text length. So my idea is every time the `CellBeginEdit` starts, we set the `AutoSizeMode` to DisplayedCells and when the `CellEndEdit` starts we save the Width (which is autosized for you) before reseting the `AutoSizeMode` to `None`, then assign the column Width to that saved value. Here is my code:

```
//First before loading data
private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   dataGridView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
   //Fill your dataGridView here
   //.........
   //.........
   int w = dataGridView.Columns[0].Width;
   //reset to None
   dataGridView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
   dataGridView.Columns[0].Width = w;
}
//Now for CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit
private void dataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ColumnIndex == 0) //because I suppose the interested column here is Columns[0]
           dataGridView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
    }
private void dataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ColumnIndex == 0){
          int w = dataGridView.Columns[0].Width;
          dataGridView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
          dataGridView.Columns[0].Width = w;
        }
    }
```

I tested the code and it seems to work OK, there is a case that it won't work because we don't add code for that case, that is when the Cell value is changed by code.

I have to say that your want is a little strange, I don't care too much about the column's width, user should know how to do with it.

Answer (score 6):

You can call the sub `DataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells)` whenever it's convenient, such as after you've loaded the data. Leave the `DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode` property alone and the user will still be able to resize the columns themselves, but they'll have a comfortable start. Best of both worlds.

Comment: Approach worked for me. The only real issue was the need of calling `Refresh()` on the `DataGridView` before calling `AutoResizeColumns(int columnIndex, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode dataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode)`

Answer (score 1):

**Row:**

```
dataGridView1.AutoResizeRow(2, DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
```

**Column:**

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: thanks @Gorfi, but with allcells is the same, can't edit the size

Answer (score 0):

In one of my applications, I have autosize set to displayedcells.  Then once the form is loaded, I turn off autosize in order to allow the users to do the sizing.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //  Designer has autosize set to displayedcells.
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;   // Turn off autosize
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = true;                                 // Turn on letting user size columns
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me in Visual Studio 2008 (and VB.net) was:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To grdList2.Columns.Count - 1
  If i <> (grdList2.Columns.Count - 1) Then
   grdList2.Columns(i).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
  Else
   grdList2.Columns(i).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
  End If
 Next
```